# Language support for Salesforce DuplicateManagement

Tags: apex, lightning, duplicate-management, language, localization

What are the languages supported by salesforce duplicate management feature?

Unfortunately my attempt to match accounts with languages other than English failed.

Thanks for your time,
Sriram